# Failure to install Tomcat using Esri provided Chef scripts

Tags: linux, tomcat, arcgis-enterprise, chef, cinc

A chef (cinc) script has been used to configure our ArcGIS Enterprise deployment for some time, as we spin up new machines. No configuration changes have been made, however it now fails on the step to install the esri-tomcat recipe. Stacktrace included below after config file. I see a error 301 http response from trying to get the tomcat tarball checksum, however, when I curl the url from the machine running the installing i get a valid 200 response.

CONFIG FILE:

```
    {
        "java": {
            "version": "11",
            "tarball_path": "/opt/software/archives/openjdk-11_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz"
        },
        "tomcat": {
            "version": "9.0.48",
            "tarball_path": "/opt/software/archives/apache-tomcat-9.0.48.tar.gz",
            "install_path": "/opt/tomcat_arcgis_9.0.48",
            "keystore_file": "/nfs/InstallMedia/ArcGISEnterprise1091/SSLCert/cert-2024.pfx",
            "keystore_type": "pkcs12",
            "keystore_password": "supersecretpassword"
        },
        "run_list": [
            "recipe[arcgis-enterprise::system]",
            "recipe[arcgis-enterprise::localserver]",
            "recipe[esri-tomcat::openjdk]",
            "recipe[esri-tomcat]"
    ]
}
```

ERROR MESSAGE:

```
15:07:11 Recipe: esri-tomcat::install
15:07:11   * tomcat_install[arcgis] action install
15:07:11     * apt_package[tar, gzip] action install (up to date)
15:07:11     * group[tomcat_arcgis] action create (up to date)
15:07:11     * linux_user[tomcat_arcgis] action create (up to date)
15:07:11     * directory[tomcat install dir] action create (up to date)
15:07:11     * remote_file[apache 9.0.48 tarball] action create[2024-02-21T22:08:05+00:00] FATAL: Fetching the Tomcat tarball checksum at http://archive.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-9/v9.0.48/bin/apache-tomcat-9.0.48.tar.gz.sha512 resulted in an error 301
```

STACKTRACE:

```
Generated at 2024-02-21 22:08:05 +0000
RuntimeError: tomcat_install[arcgis] (esri-tomcat::install line 22) had an error: RuntimeError: remote_file[apache 9.0.48 tarball] (esri-tomcat::install line 75) had an error: RuntimeError: 
/root/.cinc/local-mode-cache/cache/cookbooks/tomcat/libraries/install_helpers.rb:68:in `fetch_tomcat_checksum'
/root/.cinc/local-mode-cache/cache/cookbooks/tomcat/libraries/install_helpers.rb:83:in `validate_tomcat_checksum'
/opt/cinc/embedded/lib/ruby/3.1.0/forwardable.rb:238:in `validate_tomcat_checksum'
/opt/cinc/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/chef-18.4.2/lib/chef/resource.rb:1342:in `method_missing'
/root/.cinc/local-mode-cache/cache/cookbooks/tomcat/resources/install.rb:78:in `block (3 levels) in class_from_file'
/opt/cinc/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/chef-18.4.2/lib/chef/resource/file/verification.rb:109:in `verify_block'
/opt/cinc/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/chef-18.4.2/lib/chef/resource/file/verification.rb:98:in `verify'
/opt/cinc/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/chef-18.4.2/lib/chef/provider/file.rb:345:in `block in do_validate_content'
/opt/cinc/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/chef-18.4.2/lib/chef/provider/file.rb:344:in `each'
/opt/cinc/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/chef-18.4.2/lib/chef/provider/file.rb:344:in `do_validate_content'
/opt/cinc/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/chef-18.4.2/lib/chef/provider/file.rb:144:in `block in <class:File>'
(eval):2:in `block in action_create'
/opt/cinc/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/chef-18.4.2/lib/chef/provider.rb:304:in `instance_eval'
/opt/cinc/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/chef-18.4.2/lib/chef/provider.rb:304:in `compile_and_converge_action'
(eval):2:in `action_create'
/opt/cinc/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/chef-18.4.2/lib/chef/provider.rb:245:in `run_action'
/opt/cinc/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/chef-18.4.2/lib/chef/resource.rb:601:in `block in run_action'
/opt/cinc/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/chef-18.4.2/lib/chef/resource.rb:628:in `with_umask'
/opt/cinc/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/chef-18.4.2/lib/chef/resource.rb:600:in `run_action'
/opt/cinc/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/chef-18.4.2/lib/chef/runner.rb:74:in `run_action'
/opt/cinc/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/chef-18.4.2/lib/chef/runner.rb:108:in `block in run_all_actions'
/opt/cinc/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/chef-18.4.2/lib/chef/runner.rb:108:in `each'
/opt/cinc/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/chef-18.4.2/lib/chef/runner.rb:108:in `run_all_actions'
/opt/cinc/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/chef-18.4.2/lib/chef/resource_collection.rb:64:in `insert'
/opt/cinc/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/chef-18.4.2/lib/chef/dsl/declare_resource.rb:267:in `declare_resource'
/opt/cinc/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/chef-18.4.2/lib/chef/dsl/resources.rb:36:in `remote_file'
/root/.cinc/local-mode-cache/cache/cookbooks/tomcat/resources/install.rb:75:in `block in class_from_file'
(eval):2:in `block in action_install'
/opt/cinc/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/chef-18.4.2/lib/chef/provider.rb:304:in `instance_eval'
/opt/cinc/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/chef-18.4.2/lib/chef/provider.rb:304:in `compile_and_converge_action'
(eval):2:in `action_install'
/opt/cinc/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/chef-18.4.2/lib/chef/provider.rb:245:in `run_action'
/opt/cinc/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/chef-18.4.2/lib/chef/resource.rb:601:in `block in run_action'
/opt/cinc/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/chef-18.4.2/lib/chef/resource.rb:628:in `with_umask'
/opt/cinc/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/chef-18.4.2/lib/chef/resource.rb:600:in `run_action'
/opt/cinc/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/chef-18.4.2/lib/chef/runner.rb:74:in `run_action'
/opt/cinc/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/chef-18.4.2/lib/chef/runner.rb:108:in `block in run_all_actions'
/opt/cinc/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/chef-18.4.2/lib/chef/runner.rb:108:in `each'
/opt/cinc/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/chef-18.4.2/lib/chef/runner.rb:108:in `run_all_actions'
/opt/cinc/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/chef-18.4.2/lib/chef/runner.rb:132:in `block in converge'
/opt/cinc/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/chef-18.4.2/lib/chef/resource_collection/resource_list.rb:96:in `block in execute_each_resource'
/opt/cinc/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/chef-18.4.2/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:114:in `call_iterator_block'
/opt/cinc/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/chef-18.4.2/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:85:in `step'
/opt/cinc/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/chef-18.4.2/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:103:in `iterate'
/opt/cinc/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/chef-18.4.2/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:54:in `each_with_index'
/opt/cinc/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/chef-18.4.2/lib/chef/resource_collection/resource_list.rb:94:in `execute_each_resource'
/opt/cinc/embedded/lib/ruby/3.1.0/forwardable.rb:238:in `execute_each_resource'
/opt/cinc/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/chef-18.4.2/lib/chef/runner.rb:130:in `converge'
/opt/cinc/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/chef-18.4.2/lib/chef/client.rb:869:in `block in converge'
/opt/cinc/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/chef-18.4.2/lib/chef/client.rb:864:in `catch'
/opt/cinc/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/chef-18.4.2/lib/chef/client.rb:864:in `converge'
/opt/cinc/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/chef-18.4.2/lib/chef/client.rb:888:in `converge_and_save'
/opt/cinc/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/chef-18.4.2/lib/chef/client.rb:298:in `run'
/opt/cinc/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/chef-18.4.2/lib/chef/application.rb:305:in `run_with_graceful_exit_option'
/opt/cinc/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/chef-18.4.2/lib/chef/application.rb:281:in `block in run_chef_client'
/opt/cinc/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/chef-18.4.2/lib/chef/local_mode.rb:42:in `with_server_connectivity'
/opt/cinc/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/chef-18.4.2/lib/chef/application.rb:264:in `run_chef_client'
/opt/cinc/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/chef-18.4.2/lib/chef/application/base.rb:354:in `run_application'
/opt/cinc/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/chef-18.4.2/lib/chef/application.rb:67:in `run'
/opt/cinc/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/chef-bin-18.4.2/bin/cinc-client:25:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/bin/cinc-client:183:in `load'
/usr/bin/cinc-client:183:in `<main>'

>>>> Caused by RuntimeError: 
/root/.cinc/local-mode-cache/cache/cookbooks/tomcat/libraries/install_helpers.rb:68:in `fetch_tomcat_checksum'
/root/.cinc/local-mode-cache/cache/cookbooks/tomcat/libraries/install_helpers.rb:83:in `validate_tomcat_checksum'
/opt/cinc/embedded/lib/ruby/3.1.0/forwardable.rb:238:in `validate_tomcat_checksum'
/opt/cinc/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/chef-18.4.2/lib/chef/resource.rb:1342:in `method_missing'
/root/.cinc/local-mode-cache/cache/cookbooks/tomcat/resources/install.rb:78:in `block (3 levels) in class_from_file'
/opt/cinc/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/chef-18.4.2/lib/chef/resource/file/verification.rb:109:in `verify_block'
/opt/cinc/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/chef-18.4.2/lib/chef/resource/file/verification.rb:98:in `verify'
/opt/cinc/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/chef-18.4.2/lib/chef/provider/file.rb:345:in `block in do_validate_content'
/opt/cinc/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/chef-18.4.2/lib/chef/provider/file.rb:344:in `each'
/opt/cinc/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/chef-18.4.2/lib/chef/provider/file.rb:344:in `do_validate_content'
/opt/cinc/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/chef-18.4.2/lib/chef/provider/file.rb:144:in `block in <class:File>'
(eval):2:in `block in action_create'
/opt/cinc/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/chef-18.4.2/lib/chef/provider.rb:304:in `instance_eval'
/opt/cinc/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/chef-18.4.2/lib/chef/provider.rb:304:in `compile_and_converge_action'
(eval):2:in `action_create'
/opt/cinc/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/chef-18.4.2/lib/chef/provider.rb:245:in `run_action'
/opt/cinc/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/chef-18.4.2/lib/chef/resource.rb:601:in `block in run_action'
/opt/cinc/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/chef-18.4.2/lib/chef/resource.rb:628:in `with_umask'
/opt/cinc/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/chef-18.4.2/lib/chef/resource.rb:600:in `run_action'
/opt/cinc/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/chef-18.4.2/lib/chef/runner.rb:74:in `run_action'
/opt/cinc/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/chef-18.4.2/lib/chef/runner.rb:108:in `block in run_all_actions'
/opt/cinc/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/chef-18.4.2/lib/chef/runner.rb:108:in `each'
/opt/cinc/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/chef-18.4.2/lib/chef/runner.rb:108:in `run_all_actions'
/opt/cinc/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/chef-18.4.2/lib/chef/resource_collection.rb:64:in `insert'
/opt/cinc/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/chef-18.4.2/lib/chef/dsl/declare_resource.rb:267:in `declare_resource'
/opt/cinc/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/chef-18.4.2/lib/chef/dsl/resources.rb:36:in `remote_file'
/root/.cinc/local-mode-cache/cache/cookbooks/tomcat/resources/install.rb:75:in `block in class_from_file'
(eval):2:in `block in action_install'
/opt/cinc/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/chef-18.4.2/lib/chef/provider.rb:304:in `instance_eval'
/opt/cinc/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/chef-18.4.2/lib/chef/provider.rb:304:in `compile_and_converge_action'
(eval):2:in `action_install'
/opt/cinc/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/chef-18.4.2/lib/chef/provider.rb:245:in `run_action'
/opt/cinc/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/chef-18.4.2/lib/chef/resource.rb:601:in `block in run_action'
/opt/cinc/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/chef-18.4.2/lib/chef/resource.rb:628:in `with_umask'
/opt/cinc/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/chef-18.4.2/lib/chef/resource.rb:600:in `run_action'
/opt/cinc/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/chef-18.4.2/lib/chef/runner.rb:74:in `run_action'
/opt/cinc/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/chef-18.4.2/lib/chef/runner.rb:108:in `block in run_all_actions'
/opt/cinc/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/chef-18.4.2/lib/chef/runner.rb:108:in `each'
/opt/cinc/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/chef-18.4.2/lib/chef/runner.rb:108:in `run_all_actions'
/opt/cinc/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/chef-18.4.2/lib/chef/runner.rb:132:in `block in converge'
/opt/cinc/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/chef-18.4.2/lib/chef/resource_collection/resource_list.rb:96:in `block in execute_each_resource'
/opt/cinc/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/chef-18.4.2/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:114:in `call_iterator_block'
/opt/cinc/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/chef-18.4.2/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:85:in `step'
/opt/cinc/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/chef-18.4.2/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:103:in `iterate'
/opt/cinc/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/chef-18.4.2/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:54:in `each_with_index'
/opt/cinc/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/chef-18.4.2/lib/chef/resource_collection/resource_list.rb:94:in `execute_each_resource'
/opt/cinc/embedded/lib/ruby/3.1.0/forwardable.rb:238:in `execute_each_resource'
/opt/cinc/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/chef-18.4.2/lib/chef/runner.rb:130:in `converge'
/opt/cinc/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/chef-18.4.2/lib/chef/client.rb:869:in `block in converge'
/opt/cinc/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/chef-18.4.2/lib/chef/client.rb:864:in `catch'
/opt/cinc/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/chef-18.4.2/lib/chef/client.rb:864:in `converge'
/opt/cinc/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/chef-18.4.2/lib/chef/client.rb:888:in `converge_and_save'
/opt/cinc/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/chef-18.4.2/lib/chef/client.rb:298:in `run'
/opt/cinc/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/chef-18.4.2/lib/chef/application.rb:305:in `run_with_graceful_exit_option'
/opt/cinc/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/chef-18.4.2/lib/chef/application.rb:281:in `block in run_chef_client'
/opt/cinc/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/chef-18.4.2/lib/chef/local_mode.rb:42:in `with_server_connectivity'
/opt/cinc/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/chef-18.4.2/lib/chef/application.rb:264:in `run_chef_client'
/opt/cinc/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/chef-18.4.2/lib/chef/application/base.rb:354:in `run_application'
/opt/cinc/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/chef-18.4.2/lib/chef/application.rb:67:in `run'
/opt/cinc/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/chef-bin-18.4.2/bin/cinc-client:25:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/bin/cinc-client:183:in `load'
/usr/bin/cinc-client:183:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this issue documented in the github repository. For anyone else encountering this there is the workaround.

https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-cookbook/issues/380